# Need help getting an image to move, I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: image

Having an issue getting an image to move can someone give me some assistance? the web page is carymcclure.com trying to get the mail slot to move to the right of the door.

here is the html code:

```
body {
 width:40%;
 background-image: url("../img/background.gif");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;          
  }
 </style>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Welcome to Cary McClures' Portfolio</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link href="../css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body background="../img/background.gif" class="embed-responsive">

<a href="mailto:chef@carymcclure.com">
<img 
    style="float:right; margin-left:1000px; margin-top:350px" 
    src="../img/slot.gif" 
    width="216" 
    height="89" 
    alt="email" />
</a>
  
  
<a href="library.html">
<img 
    style="position:absolute; left:542px"
     src="../img/door.gif" width="850" height="1049" alt="door"/>
   </a>
```

thanks

Comment: There isn't much space to the right of door or are you just trying to move mail to right even if it's both on wall and door?

Comment: trying to get it to just the right of the door on the wall - going for a library theme so wanting it to loo like a book drop next to the door

Comment: curious I use dreamweaver and whe I use the preview button everything is where it is supposed to be but when I upload to host site it all moved around, any reason why?

Comment: Why is the preview in Dreamweaver completely different to what is seen in Chrome? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: well curious since when i put up the preview from dreamweaver and it opens my edge program everything is in the right place but when I open as a regular page it is all bunched up like what is on my webpage now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you just want to show the button to the right on the door. Then the following inline CSS code will work for you on the  of the button.

```
<a href="mailto:chef@carymcclure.com" style="position: absolute;right: 100px;z-index: 100;">
    <img style="float:right;margin-right:105px;margin-top:350px;position: relative;" src="../img/slot.gif" width="216" height="89" alt="email">
    </a>
```

Comment: tried that code but when I uploaded it still in the wrong place, not sure why

Comment: can you look at it at carymcclure.com maybe it is just me.. I appreciate all of your help

Comment: I checked by implementing the CSS and it's working. Please check the screenshot on the following link. [link](https://prnt.sc/1jv3ia5)

Comment: @chefcj Have you tried the solution? Please let me know if you still have any concerns. I will feel more than happy to assist you to fix out this issue.

Comment: i tried it but it didn't seem to do anything, can you look at my page at carymcclure.com I changed it and uploaded but it didn't seem to change

Comment: @chefcj It seems like your site isn't working [link](https://prnt.sc/1jw7rpm). Can you please share your server access to fix this issue quickly?

Comment: thanks to you all I have gotten it figured out thanks so much for your help

Comment: @chefcj Can you please accept the answer if it really helps you to figure out the issue?